# changing pitch of an sound file and save to mp3 file

Tags: android, audio, mp3, soundpool

changing pitch:

```
soundPool = new SoundPool(50, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
/** Sound ID for Later handling of sound pool **/
soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sounds, 1);
```

play:

```
 streamId = soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 3, pitch);
```

How can I save the file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with the SoundPool, as it does not allow you to work at a byte level. I think you want to look into using [AudioTracks.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html.)